# MVC3 areas and routing structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am making Areas for User, Admin, Shop, Forum... etc

In each area, it has its own Controllers, Models, Views folders. At the root Models, root Controllers and root Views I have shared components in them.

Structure A:

```
Root/ -> Models/, Controllers/, Views/
Root/User/ -> Models/, Controllers/, Views/
Root/Admin/ -> Models/, Controllers/, Views/
Root/Shop/ -> Models/, Controllers/, Views/
Root/Forum/ -> Models/, Controllers/, Views/
```

I maybe wrong, but they really don't look DRY to me to repeat M V and C folders in each of the business logic groups. I was thinking a better structure would be using M V and C as the main folders and layout my business logic groups in them:

Structure B:

```
Root/Views/ -> User/, Admin/, Shop/, Forum/ ...etc
Root/Models/ -> User/, Admin/, Shop/, Forum/ ...etc
Root/Controllers/ -> User/, Admin/, Shop/, Forum/ ...etc
```

But if I do structure the folders this way, I lost the area (or from users point of view, the sub folder path) ability to divde logical functionalities of the website.

e.g.

with structure A, I can do:

```
www.mywebsite.com/Users(area)/Account(controller)/LogOn(action)
www.mywebsite.com/Admin(area)/Account(controller)/LogOn(action)
```

Notice I can have same controller and action names with different areas.

With structure B, best I can do is:

```
www.mywebsite.com/AdminAccount(controller)/LogOn(action)
www.mywebsite.com/UserAccount(controller)/LogOn(action)
```

It can not achieve the single-word sub-folder result without area. If not only that, the controller names here can get longer and more messy very soon. Not to mention you have a large group of actions stacking in same controller.cs file.

So, anyway, my point is, if I find Structure B making more sense to me, how do I go about configuring routing to achieve that?

Comment: You repeat just as much with structure B. Think of areas being something like their own "projects" in your app; allowing better separation of concerns for independent blocks of functionality. In that view, only structure A makes sense.

Comment: @Lucero, in reality, we can't consider areas as their own "projects"? e.g. User area, after a user login, he will go to "shop" or "forum" area, they are all related, and use many shared components. So, it goes back to my concern of repeating M V and C in each folder and root folder. It Doesn't look very DRY

Comment: A shop or a forum are fundamentally different, and while they may share some code, they certainly can be seen as being "projects" of their own. Or even real projects if you use the Portable Area approach from MvcContrib (which allows externalizing MVC areas into their own class library projects, creating a real separation and enabling re-use and pluggability across different MVC sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want Structure B with url's corresponding to A?

You'll be giving up convention over configuration.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UserAccount", // Route name
            "users/account/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserAccount", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Another option would be to write a custom route handler and introduce your own convention.  Something like the following (new convention would be to concatenate Users and Account to get the UsersAccountController in www.mywebsite.com/Users/Account/LogOn).  I did not test to see how this handles areas, but if you have issues let me know and I can take a look.

```
public class CustomConventionRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string controller = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        object controllerModifier;
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("controllerModifier", out controllerModifier))
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = string.Concat(controllerModifier, controller);
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(
        new Route(
            "{controllerModifier}/{controller}/{action}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controllerModifier = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index" }),  //defaults
            new CustomConventionRouteHandler()));
}
```

Comment: Nice. Your first piece code seems like what I want. Because there are two map routes. So I belive both /UserAccount/ and /User/Account/ will work in the browser. I am giving it a try.

Comment: I think you're right about them both working.  If its a problem you can add a constraint to the default route disallowing /UserAccount/.  Could also disable it with a stop route.  If you do not disallow the route you should confirm that there isn't an effect on things like @Url.Action which uses the routing table to create links.

Comment: Note, areas have to be set in the route `DataTokens` (value key: `area`) for the framework to look into the areas for the controller specified.